# Need to get rid of space between top image and second div

Tags: css, html

so I'm trying to set up a website and I want the green nav bar to be flush with the bottom of the image. However, no matter what changes I make to the source code and css it still leaves a space. Does anyone know how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <img src="xyz.gif">
  <div class="hasbackground">
     ...
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.hasbackground { background-color: blue; }
```

Here's an example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a1mn0ytz/

Thanks

Comment: Dude, what have you tried? Where do you think is the offending CSS? What do you need help understanding? How about a jsfiddle? This isn't a "fix my crappy code" site

Comment: The problem is i'm unaware of where the "offending css" is, that's why I'm posting here. I've multiple things, adding margins, paddings, top restrictions, removing divs, moving divs, replacing divs. Nothing was giving me the desired effect. I've even checked html tutorial sites and nothing has helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is `display: inline`, but it needs to be `display: block`. Elements that are `inline` or `inline-block` treat white space as if it's inline (e.g. the spaces between these words.) That can sometimes manifest vertically, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 2 pixel border you have on the image.

Change

```
<img width="946" height="246" style="border:2px solid #000000" alt="dogwash" src="Banner.jpg">
```

to

```
<img width="946" height="246" alt="dogwash" src="Banner.jpg">
```

Comment: So when i take off the border, I need to add the 4 pixels back to the width and height of the image otherwise there is green below and to the right of the image. So when i resize the image to accomodate for the loss of a border it puts the space back in. The website is updated with the border being gone.

Answer (score 0):

The border of attribute of the image is following:

```
border: 2px solid #000000;
```

Change it to following:

```
border-left: 2px solid #000000;
border-right: 2px solid #000000;
```